# Having trouble identifying matching characters in two strings

Tags: python

I am able to iterate through two given strings of the same length.

I am supposed to output a green emoji if the letters in `guess_word` are are also contained and in the correct position of the `secret_word`. If a letter in the `guess_word` is in the `secret_word` but it's in the wrong position, then I should have an output of a yellow emoji.

This is where my issue is. The yellow emoji is not showing up in my output, only the green and white boxes. I have a picture below of what it should look like in the output.

I have to stick to two different functions because this is what my homework is asking me to do.

```
def contains_char(any_length: str, single_character: str) -> bool:
    """Loop iterates through each character in string to find matching character."""
    assert len(single_character) == 1
    if single_character in any_length:
        return True 
    else:
        return False

def emojified(guess_word: str, secret_word: str) -> str:
    """A way to match letters to its corresponding emoji color output. """
    assert len(guess_word) == len(secret_word)
    WHITE_BOX: str = "\U00002B1C"
    GREEN_BOX: str = "\U0001F7E9"
    YELLOW_BOX: str = "\U0001F7E8"
    emoji_color: str = ""
    i: int = 0 
    while i < len(secret_word):
        i += 1
        if guess_word[0] in secret_word[0]:
            emoji_color += GREEN_BOX
            i += 1
        else:
            emoji_color += WHITE_BOX
            i += 1
        if contains_char is True:
            emoji_color += YELLOW_BOX
        else:
            emoji_color += WHITE_BOX
    return emoji_color
```

Output:

[image: output]

Comment: You seem to be always testing the first letter via `if guess_word[0] in secret_word[0]`.

Comment: Just a side tip: if you want the `contains_char()` function to be more compact, you could remove the `if`/`else` blocks and just use `return single_character in any_length`

Comment: `contains_char` is a function - you need to call it. `contains_char is True` will always be false, because a function is not a boolean.

Comment: `contains_char` is a function and is never the same as `True`. Did you mean to check if it *returns* `True`?

Comment: @jarmod how could I test all the letters?

Comment: @PaulM. how do I call a function? I edited it to be ```def contains_char():``` but how would I encode the yellow emoji after that?

Comment: Check if `guess_word[i] == secret_word[i]` (green) else if `guess_word[i] in secret_word` (yellow) else (white).

Answer (score 1):

In order to properly process the "same-position" matches without interfering with the "different-position" matched, you need to check for same-positions first and fallback on diffrent-position matches otherwise.

You can do this by replacing characters in a comprehension that you join into the final result.

For example:

```
def emojified(guess,secret):
    WHITE_BOX  = "\U00002B1C"
    GREEN_BOX  = "\U0001F7E9"
    YELLOW_BOX = "\U0001F7E8"

    return "".join( GREEN_BOX  if s==g            # same-position
               else YELLOW_BOX if g in secret     # different-position
               else WHITE_BOX                     # no match
                    for s,g in zip(secret,guess)) # character pairs
```

Output:

```
print(emojified("hello","world"))   # ⬜️⬜️
print(emojified("elloh","hello"))   # 
print(emojified("python","woohoo")) # ⬜️⬜️⬜️⬜️
print(emojified("python","python")) # 
print(emojified("yikyak","tiktok")) # ⬜️⬜️⬜️
```

Answer (score 0):

Without changing too much, here's how I would write your while-loop:

```
while i < len(secret_word):
    guess_char = guess_word[i]
    secret_char = secret_word[i]

    current_emoji = WHITE_BOX # By default, we display a white box for this position

    if contains_char(secret_word, guess_char):
        current_emoji = YELLOW_BOX # guess_char is in secret_word. guess_char may even be in the correct position, but we don't care about that yet.

    if guess_char == secret_char:
        current_emoji = GREEN_BOX # guess_char is in the correct position.

    emoji_color += current_emoji
    i += 1
return emoji_color
```